# Can't enqueue scripts or styles in WordPress custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a WordPress theme from scratch (no child theme) and I am not able to enqueue any styles or js in the functions.php file. I have done this before several times already and it never was a problem. Now I am sitting here for hours and everything I research is telling me that my code is correct. But it still has no effect.

I even have opened an old functions.php file from a theme that I have created before. The code is identical. This is my functions.php file. If I put an echo at the beginning, the echo gets printed so this file is definitely called and I don't have a caching problem. There is also no caching plugin installed yet since it's a fresh installation.

Does anyone have an idea what it could be?

Thanks a lot.

```
<?php

/* begin register style sheets */

function bh24_registerThemeStyles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('bootstrap_css'));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bh24_registerThemeStyles');

/* end register style sheets */

/* begin register javascript */

function bh24_registerThemeJS() {
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('bh24_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array('bootstrap_js'), '', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bh24_registerThemeJS');

/* end register javascript */

?>
```

Comment: Did you check the file paths you're using in get_template_directory_uri() are correct? Also, check that the dependencies for each script are correct. If jquery is not enqueued before bootstrap_js, it might cause issues.

Comment: I did echo the get_template_directory_uri() to make sure and it was the correct one. I also did uncomment the css part and focused on making the js part work first . I also tried to just load the app.js  without any dependencies, but still no effect.

Comment: `get_stylesheet_uri()` returns the URL to `style.css`, so concatenating`'/css/bootstrap.min.css'` on to it doesn't make sense, you definitely want `get_template_directory_uri()` everywhere.

Comment: Verify that the wp_head() and wp_footer() functions are present in your header.php and footer.php files, respectively. Ensure that the file permissions for your CSS and JS files allow them to be read by WordPress.Use wp_enqueue_style() and wp_enqueue_script() with hardcoded URLs to your stylesheets and scripts to check if they work when not concatenated with get_stylesheet_uri() or get_template_directory_uri()

Comment: Of course you are right I have started from scratch and haven't added wp_head and wp_footer yet. That would never work. I feel so stupid. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Just to finish this question. The comment from user580950 is absolutely correct as is Chris and after updating my code, the problem is solved. Thanks again guys.

Comment: MikeQuade, I'm glad you resolved your problem. If you think that this question and your resolution would be helpful to future readers, could you or @user580950 post an answer? If you don't feel an answer is warranted, the general guidance is usually to just close the question itself, since [comments are often ignored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294792/231316) by future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I started working on the functions.php first and I totally ignored the fact that I needed to have a basic page template (or at least an index.php) ready in order for it to work (see the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) here).

At the very least I needed to call the wp_head() function in the header.php file and the wp_footer() function in the footer.php file of my template and then include both with the get_header() and get_footer() functions in my page template so that all scripts, styles, meta tags and other declarations are being rendered.

I worked on a WordPress plugin last and there I didn't need to worry about template files, so I got a little confused and forgot about that part. Thanks to user580950 for providing the solution.